# Html.ValidationSummary doesn't show off when valid data is entered

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I'm working on a project which uses ASPNET MVC 3, unobstrusive javascript and Razor

I have a partial view with Ajax.BeginForm containing fields like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "txt-input", placeholder = "Eg. First Name", maxlength = 50 })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "*", new { @class = "form-comments redtxt" })
```

Then at the end of the form I have this:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please complete the required fields", new { @class = "form-comments redtxt" })
```

When I enter no value it correctly shows `"*"` near the textbox, and "Please complete the required fields" in the validation summary.
The problem is that when I enter a correct value only the `"*"` disspears and the "Please complete the required fields" remains.

I need to add this in the css in order to not show `"*"` nor the "Please complete the required fields" when the patial view is loaded for the first time.

```
.validation-summary-valid
{
    display: none;
}

.field-validation-valid 
{
    display: none;
}
```

How can I make the validation summary dissapear when valid data is entered?

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Comment: Is this all happening on client-side, or still happening even as the view posts back to the server?  Do you have client-side validation enabled?

Comment: It seems to be on client side. I do have client side validation enabled.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As why it's still displaying I don't know.

But a quick fix is to put an if block around your `@Html.ValidationSummary` and check to see if the model is valid

```
@ if(!ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid){

@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please complete the required fields", new { @class = "form-comments redtxt" })

}
```

I usually put my validation summary in a dialog and i just don't display the dialog div if Page.IsValid is true

--Update here is a code snippet that I know works

```
    @{ if(!ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid){
<div id="errors" class="DisplayErrors">
 @Html.ValidationSummary()
</div>
}}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".Date").datepicker();
        $(".button").button();
        $(".DisplayErrors").dialog({ autoOpen: true, title:"Errors" });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Strange it says Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type '<null>'

Comment: Updated the Answer, you have to check ModelState not Page, what do you mean by client side? on the view? or after a ajax post?

Comment: I updated the answer with something I know works, as to why your isn't showing up, don't know

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for replying back.
What does the dialog do? I mean, It's a jQuery dialog, isn't it? If so, I can't use it due to business request.

Comment: the JQuery aside, I just grabbed a code snippet from a project that I know works, it will still work if you remove the script tag

Comment: This condition is evaluated on the server so doesn't help for client side validation

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood ur problem, u can use below written code. Its just a hack.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('form')
        .find('input')
        .bind('keyup', function () {
            var _summary = jQuery('.form-comments');
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                _summary.hide();
            }
            else {
                _summary.show();
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, the problem with your code is that I have more than one textboxes in the form and if there are more than one of them with errors and I start to fix them populating the values the summary can be hidden when not all the textboxes have valid values.